# ¿Cómo abrir un FXML luego de iniciar sesion?

Tags: java, xml, javafx

Hola Soy nuevo en JavaFX, deseo conocer como abrir un FXML luego de un inicio de sesión, y que este se cargue sin decoración, ademas de poderle mover de una lado a otro con el mouse cuando se de click en alguna parte del formulario...
Quedo atento a sus respuestas..

quiero llamar a un documento "fxml" despues del login

Este es el login que tengo FXMLDocument.fxml

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.Cursor?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Hyperlink?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="543.0" prefWidth="494.0" style="-fx-background-color: #ffffff;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.141" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="controlador.FXMLDocumentController">
   <children>

       <ImageView fitHeight="525.0" fitWidth="487.0" layoutX="7.0" layoutY="1.0" opacity="0.3" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
         <image>
            <Image url="@../imagenes/logo.PNG" />
         </image>
      </ImageView>

      <ImageView fitHeight="156.0" fitWidth="162.0" layoutX="172.0" layoutY="37.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="172.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="166.0">
         <image>
            <Image url="@../imagenes/cotizar.png" />
         </image>
      </ImageView>

      <ImageView fitHeight="36.0" fitWidth="171.0" layoutX="169.0" layoutY="408.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="21.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="169.0">
         <image>
            <Image url="@../imagenes/LOGO-ALTA-CMYK.png" />
         </image>
      </ImageView>

      <TextField fx:id="txtusuario" layoutX="160.0" layoutY="232.0" prefHeight="36.0" prefWidth="171.0" promptText="Usuario" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="160.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="163.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="232.0" />

      <PasswordField fx:id="txtpass" layoutX="160.0" layoutY="301.0" prefHeight="36.0" prefWidth="171.0" promptText="Contraseña" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="160.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="163.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="301.0" />

      <Button fx:id="btningresar" defaultButton="true" layoutX="162.0" layoutY="420.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleIngresar" prefHeight="36.0" prefWidth="171.0" stylesheets="@../estilos/Estilos.css" text="Ingresar" textFill="#f5f0f0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="162.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="161.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="420.0">
         <cursor>
            <Cursor fx:constant="HAND" />
         </cursor>
      </Button>

      <Label layoutX="160.0" layoutY="208.0" text="Usuario :" />
      <Label layoutX="160.0" layoutY="277.0" text="Contraseña:" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="160.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="254.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="277.0" />

      <Hyperlink layoutX="428.0" layoutY="16.0" onAction="#handleClose" text="Cerrar" />
      <Label fx:id="lblestado" layoutX="160.0" layoutY="356.0" prefHeight="36.0" prefWidth="171.0" textFill="#d00909" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Este es el controlador

```java
        package controlador;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.net.URL;
    import java.util.ResourceBundle;
    import java.util.logging.Level;
    import java.util.logging.Logger;
    import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
    import javafx.fxml.FXML;
    import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
    import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
    import javafx.scene.Parent;
    import javafx.scene.Scene;
    import javafx.scene.control.Button;
    import javafx.scene.control.Label;
    import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
    import javafx.stage.Stage;



    /**
     *
     * @author hiva
     */
    public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

        @FXML
        private TextField txtusuario; 

        @FXML
        private TextField txtpass; 

        @FXML
        private Label lblestado;

        @FXML
        private Button btningresar;

        @FXML
        private void handleClose(ActionEvent event) {
            System.exit(0);
        }

        @FXML
        private void handleIngresar(ActionEvent event) {

            Stage stage;
            Parent root;

            txtpass.setText(txtpass.getText().trim());
            txtusuario.setText(txtusuario.getText().trim());

                if(!"".equals(txtpass.getText()) & !"".equals(txtusuario.getText()))
               {
                try {
                    lblestado.setText("Datos Validos");
                    stage = (Stage) btningresar.getScene().getWindow();
                    root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/vista/FXMLMenu.fxml"));
                    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
                    stage.setTitle("Menu");
                    stage.setScene(scene);
                    stage.show();

                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(FXMLDocumentController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
               }
               else
               { 
                lblestado.setText("Datos no Validos");
               }
        }
        @Override
        public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
            // TODO
        }    

    }
```

```java
Este es el main 

        package cotizador;

    import javafx.application.Application;
    import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
    import javafx.scene.Parent;
    import javafx.scene.Scene;
    import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
    import javafx.stage.Stage;
    import javafx.stage.StageStyle;

    /**
     *
     * @author hiva
     */
    public class Cotizador extends Application {


        private double xOffset=0;
        private double yOffset=0;
        @Override
        public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/vista/FXMLDocument.fxml"));

            root.setOnMousePressed((MouseEvent event) -> {
                xOffset=event.getSceneX();
                yOffset=event.getSceneY();
            });
            root.setOnMouseDragged((MouseEvent event) -> {
                stage.setX(event.getScreenX()-xOffset);
                stage.setY(event.getScreenY()-yOffset);
            });

            Scene scene = new Scene(root);

            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.setTitle("Cotizador");
            stage.centerOnScreen();
            stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
            stage.show();


        }

        /**
         * @param args the command line arguments
         */
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            launch(args);
        }

    }

    Ahora este este es el menu que deseo abrir documento fxml

        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <?import java.net.URL?>
    <?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
    <?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
    <?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

    <AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="765.0" styleClass="mainFxmlClass" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.141" fx:controller="controlador.FXMLMenuController">
        <stylesheets>
            <URL value="@/estilos/Estilos.css" />
        </stylesheets>
       <children>
          <AnchorPane prefHeight="51.0" prefWidth="765.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
             <children>
                <ImageView fitHeight="150.0" fitWidth="216.0" layoutX="549.0" layoutY="2.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                   <image>
                      <Image url="@../imagenes/LOGO-ALTA-CMYK.png" />
                   </image>
                </ImageView>
             </children>
          </AnchorPane>
       </children>
    </AnchorPane>
```

```java
El controlador de este ...



     package controlador;

    import java.net.URL;
    import java.util.ResourceBundle;
    import javafx.fxml.Initializable;

    /**
     * FXML Controller class
     *
     * @author hiva
     */
    public class FXMLMenuController implements Initializable {

        /**
         * Initializes the controller class.
         */
        @Override
        public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
            // TODO
        }    

    }
```

Comment: Hector, que bueno saber nuevamente de ti, tu pregunta busca opiniones, trata de agregar lo que investigaste o un [mcve], revisa [ask] para que tu respuesta sea bien recibida, saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias Jorge, ya quedo actualizada la información. Agradezco sus respuestas

Answer (score 0):

La solución fue crear llamadas a metodos desde el main, y luego desde el controller principal llamar el evento boton cargando el método para abrir el nuevo fomulario.
ver codigo...

package jcotizador;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;

/**
 *
 * @author hiva
 */
public class JCotizador extends Application {

```
private Parent root;
private double xOffset=0;
private double yOffset=0;

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

    cargarLogin(stage);
}

public void cargarLogin(Stage stage){
    try {
        root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/vista/FXMLLogin.fxml"));
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(JCotizador.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    root.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            xOffset =event.getSceneX();
            yOffset =event.getSceneY();
        }
    });

    root.setOnMouseDragged(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            stage.setX(event.getScreenX() - xOffset);
            stage.setY(event.getScreenY() - yOffset);
        }
    });

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
    stage.setTitle("Inicio Sesion");
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.centerOnScreen();
    stage.show();
}

public void cargarMenu(Stage stage){
    try {
        root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/vista/FXMLMenu.fxml"));
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(JCotizador.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    root.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            xOffset =event.getSceneX();
            yOffset =event.getSceneY();
        }
    });

    root.setOnMouseDragged(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            stage.setX(event.getScreenX() - xOffset);
            stage.setY(event.getScreenY() - yOffset);
        }
    });

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    //stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
    stage.setTitle("Menu");
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.centerOnScreen();
    stage.show();
}


/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

}